# significance of setting nullok=

Tags: guidewire, gosu

What is the difference between setting `nullok=false` or `true` for the typekey field?

Answer (score 1):

This means that field can contain Null values or not.

nullok = false  ->  do not allow null value
nullok = true  -> allow null values

Comment: So a typekey field can be nullable as any other field on the entity with nullok=true

Answer (score 1):

Nullability of a column (`nullok = true`) makes it possible to persist the object even when the value for given field is missing.

Non-nullable column (`nullok = false`) does not allow missing values.

It should, however, be remembered, that **this distinction is on the logical level and might not map directly to database limitations**.

While a `nullok=true` column will always be nullable in the database, the `nullok=false` column is only non-nullable if the field is declared on the base (top level) entity. If the field comes from a subtype, the field on database level will still be technically nullable.

This is necessary because Guidewire keeps all the subtypes in a single table. A non-nullable column on a subtype would make it impossible to persist objects of subtypes that do not have related Property defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

When we set a Database Table Column to

**NULLOK = FALSE**, then that field **should always have valid data or a default data** written during every new record created or updated.

**NULLOK = TRUE**, then that field **may or may not have valid data or a default data** written during every new record created or updated.

**Significance of the NULLOK :**
We can restrict integration code or backend process to update the database column with NULL value by setting the nullok = FALSE